# Populate multiple lists from one list

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I populate three arrayLists from one list in way value from index1 into lista1, value from index2 into lista2, value from index3 into lista3, value from index4 into lista1 and so on...?

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<String>();

        sh.forEach(row -> {
                row.forEach(cell -> {
                String cellvalue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                lista.add(cellvalue);
            });
        });
```

Comment: What are `index1`, `index2`, and `index3`? The 1st 2nd and 3rd index of `lista`?

Comment: that should be indexes from ArrayList lista. Element 1, element 2, element 3 etc

Comment: are there any properties that apply to those and only those that belong in list 1 for instance, or the other ones?

Comment: 1
1
1
2
2
1
3
3
1
4
4
1
5
5
1
6
6
1      ---This are values of lista. I want to first value to be in lista1, second in lista2 and third in lista3. And then new row, fourth to lista1, fifth to lista2, sixt to lista3...

Comment: You have to iterate over all of them, check `index % 3` and add based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> lista1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lista2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> lista3 = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String>[] newLists = new ArrayList[]{lista1, lista2, lista3};
for (int i=0 ; i< lista.size(); i ++ ){
  newLists[i % 3].add(lista.get(i)); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the three list in a three-element array and use a traditional for loop to iterate over them. Here's the modified code

```
    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String>[] lists = new ArrayList[3];

    lists[0] = new ArrayList<String>();
    lists[1] = new ArrayList<String>();
    lists[2] = new ArrayList<String>();


    for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++){
        lists[i % lists.length].add(lista.get(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java8+ stream API, you can try this

```
    List<String> lista = Arrays.asList("A","B","C","D","E");

    List<String> list1 = lista.stream()
            .filter(x -> lista.indexOf(x) % 3 == 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> list2 = lista.stream()
            .filter(x -> lista.indexOf(x) % 3 == 1)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> list3 = lista.stream()
            .filter(x -> lista.indexOf(x) % 3 == 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```